# Swing JScrollPane fill one dimension and scroll another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I have relatively big text which is represented by a single `JLabel`. The text is added to the `JPanel` component with `GridBagLayout`.

I would like the text to fill all available space within the panel on the x-axis and provide scrolling only on the y-axis. Also, scrolling and text alignment should change accordingly when the panel is scaled.

So, consider the following code sample :

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JLabel desc = new JLabel("largelarge text");
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(desc, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
panel.add(scrollPane, gbc constraints here);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your [mcve]

Comment: Consider using a non-editable JTextArea (if the text is all in one font) or a JEditorPane (if the text is HTML), instead of a JLabel.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the text to fill all available space within the panel on the x-axis and provide scrolling only on the y-axis

You would need to create a custom panel and implement the `Scrollable` interface.

You would implement the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method to return “true” and the `getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()` method to return “false”. You would also need to implement the other methods of the interface to provide reasonable values.

Or, you can use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which implements all the `Scrollable` interface methods with default behaviour and provides methods to allow you to change the behaviour.